# Check if li contains ul

Tags: jquery

I cant see why my jQuery does not work in this case.
I iterate through all the li items in my nav and check each for the presence of a ul element inside, but every each returns true..?

My markup:

```
<div id="toolbar">
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="somelink">some page</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="somelink">some page</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="somelink">some page</a>
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="somelink">some page</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="somelink">some page</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
// if has children make red
$("#toolbar li").each(function(){
 if($(this).has("ul")){
    $(this).css("background", "#ff0000");
 }
 else
 {
    $(this).css("background", "#336699"); 
 }
});
```

As you can see the third top level li should return true but they all return true..?

Comment: thats because you`re selecting all lis with that selector, you should be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/PddPv/

```
$("#toolbar li").each(function(){
    $(this).css("background", $('ul', this)[0] ? "#f00" : "#369");
});
```

where `$('ul', this)[0]` is a nice way JS tells us if the element exists (the way `.length` method does) 
and `?:` is a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Thanks for the help of all you guys and i'm going to accept this answer for the beauty of its brevity.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `.has()` in correct way , `.has()` doesn't return true or false

As per `.has()` docs :

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant
>   that matches the selector or DOM element.

You can make use of has this way -

```
$(this).has("ul").css("background", "#ff0000");
$(this).not(':has(ul)').css("background", "#336699");
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/uTrLX/

http://api.jquery.com/has/

Answer (score 0):

```
// if has children make red
$("#toolbar li").each(function () {

    // This checks if finds any ul under it
    if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {
        $(this).css("background", "#ff0000");
    } else {
        $(this).css("background", "#336699");
    }
});
```

Comment: I had been there earlier today with with the same function but neglected > 0 just had .length believing it would return true or false. Thanks a million.

Comment: @Gary: `.length` obviously returns a number, not a boolean (think about what "length" means). `> 0` is actually not necessary since `0` evaluates to `false` and any other number to `true`.

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee `$.has()` returns the objects, not true or false so you would need to still check the length on the has to see if it is greater than zero. Otherwise it will always be true.

Comment: Ah ofcourse. has returns a jquery collection thing which is not null, but has a length of zero if the element is not found.

Comment: Your right .length without > 0 still works as i thought it would. I must have done something else wrong earlier or been cached and not seen my changes.

Comment: Finally with the 2 options i accept as good .has("ul").length > 0 or .find("ul").length is there 1 that out performs the other or maybe more failsafe..?

Answer (score 0):

Same as John, just this makes sure you only select the li's directly below (as child of) #toolbar, and not any more sub li's

```
// if has children make red
$("#toolbar > ul > li").each(function () {

        // This checks if finds any ul under it
        if ($(this).find("ul").length) {
                $(this).css("background", "#ff0000");
        } else {
                $(this).css("background", "#336699");
        }
});
```

Additionally you might want to consider making a class for these li's. Where #336699 is the default background-color. Then make another class that for the "has ul" li's with background-color: #ff0000. (when just setting a color i prefer background-color over background for clarity)

Comment: this won't work. toolbar > li selects only those li that are direct descendants of #toolbar. none of them are

Answer (score 0):

Here is jsfiddle for what you want:  http://jsfiddle.net/5NHet/

```
$("li").css("background", "#fff");
$("#toolbar li:has('ul')").each(function () {

// This checks if finds any ul under it

    $(this).css("background", "#ff0000");

});
```

Comment: Been there this one does not work i am afraid as noted above.

Comment: Well, I am sure it works. And it makes third level in your list to have red background. I guess that is what you looked for.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. Just add `.length > 0`.

```
if($(this).has("ul").length > 0){
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LqkLQ/)**

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this:

```
$("li").css("background", "#336699");
$("#toolbar li:has(ul)").css("background", "#ff0000");
```

This uses the has selector. That's what you wanted to do i suppose

or directly

```
 $("li").css("background", "#336699").has("ul").css("background", "#ff0000");
```

Comment: You can just use the `$.css()` without going through each. Each is no longer necessary since you aren't checking anything else.